# re.compile() doesn't match the valid pattern against a string python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

Below match doesn't work:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile("[\^\/!*\[({%?$]")

param = "f00.*"

if pattern.match(param):
    print " I am a regexp"
else:
    print "non regexp"
```

But this does:

```
import re
node_pattern = re.search("[\^\/!*\[({%?$]", "f00.*")

print bool(node_pattern)
```

What's wrong with re.compile()?

Isn't it the valid way to match a string against a regexp?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not so much about `re.compile()` as it is about the difference between `re.search()` and `re.match()`, as Lev Zakharov pointed out. This code works the way you want it to, only changing `match` to `search`:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile("[\^\/!*\[({%?$]")

param = "f00.*"

if pattern.search(param):
    print " I am a regexp"
else:
    print "non regexp"
```

Maybe you have a more specific question about your use case that we are not getting.